# Prove that: {$f_n$} converges unifromly to $f$ on $E$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||f_n-f||_u = 0$

Tags: uniform-convergence, solution-verification

Prove that: 
{$f_n$} converges unifromly to $f$ on $E$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||f_n-f||_u = 0$

I don't understand the approach for the Forward proof.

My approach is:

By definition, for $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$; hence, the smallest upper bound should also be less than the $\epsilon$ (i.e., ${sup}_{x \in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$). Thus, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||f_n-f||_u = 0$.

However, the solution uses $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as the following:

> $|f_n(x)-f| \leq {sup}_{x \in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon $
>
> ${sup}_{x \in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$
>
> ${sup}_{x \in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$

Hence, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||f_n-f||_u = 0$.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supremum preserves only weak inequalities, not strict inequalities. If all elements of a set $A$ are smaller than $\epsilon$ it only implies that $\sup (A)\leq\epsilon$, and not necessary $\sup (A)<\epsilon$. That's why they use $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. If all the elements of $A$ are less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then $\sup(A)\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$. This way we indeed get the strict inequality $\sup(A)<\epsilon$.

Not that it really matters. If you prove that for each $\epsilon>0$ we eventually have $||f_n-f||\leq\epsilon$ then it proves that $||f_n-f||\to 0$. But I guess they wanted to prove it with strict inequality.

Comment: Hi, so is that means sup(A) does not necessary have to be an element of A?

Comment: Supremum is not always an element of the set. For example, if $A=(0,1)$ then $1$ is the supremum, but it doesn't belong to the set.

Answer (score 2):

First, we define what we mean by *uniform convergence*.

> Let $E$ be any non-empty set, and let $(X, d)$ be any metric space. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \colon E \to X$ be a function, and let $f \colon E \to X$ be any given function. Then the sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ of functions *converges uniformly* to the function $f$ on set $E$ if, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N = N(\varepsilon)$ [This means that this $N$ in general depends on our choice of the $\varepsilon$ (alone).] such that 
>   $$ d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) < \varepsilon \tag{1} $$
>   for all $s \in E$ and for any natural number $n > N$.

Then the result I think can be stated in full generality as follows:

> Let $E$ be any non-empty set, and let $(X, d)$ be any metric space. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \colon E \to X$ be a function, and let $f \colon E \to X$ be any given function. Then the sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ of functions converges uniformly to the function $f$ on $E$ if and only if 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u = 0. $$
>   For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define $\left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u$  as follows:
>   $$ \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u \colon= \sup \left\{ \, d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) \, \colon \, s \in E \, \right\}, \tag{2} $$
>   and the last supremum is to be considered in the *extended* real number system.

Proof:

> First, suppose that the sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to the function $f$ on set $E$.
>
> Let us arbitrarily choose a real number $\varepsilon > 0$. Then for the real number $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} > 0$, we can choose a natural number $N$ such that 
>   $$ d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
>   for all $s \in E$ and for all natural numbers $n > N$. Refer to (1) above. Here we have simply applied our definition above of *uniform convergence* with $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ in place of $\varepsilon$.
>
> Thus for any natural number $n > N$, the set 
>   $$ \left\{ \, d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) \, \colon \, s \in E \, \right\} \tag{3} $$
>   is a non-empty bounded above subset of the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers, the real number $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ being one of the upper bounds of this set. Therefore we can conclude that, for any natural number $n > N$, we have 
>   $$ \sup \left\{ \, d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) \, \colon \, s \in E \, \right\} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
>   that is, 
>   $$ \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2};  $$
>   [Refer to (2) above.] but since the set in (3) above consists only of non-negative real numbers, therefore we can conclude that, for any natural number $n > N$, the following holds:
>   $$ 0 \leq \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{4} $$
>
> However, as $\varepsilon > 0$, so $$ -\varepsilon < 0 \ \mbox{ and } \  \frac{ \varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon, $$
>   and therefore (4) implies that
>   $$ -\varepsilon <  \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u \leq \varepsilon  $$
>   for any natural number $n > N$. Thus for any natural number $n > N$, we have
>   $$ \big\lvert \, \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u  \, - \, 0  \, \big\rvert < \varepsilon. \tag{5} $$ Here we have used a familiar property of real numbers and their absolute values.
>
> But $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrarily chosen positive real number. Thus for any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that (5) holds for any natural number $n > N$. Hence 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u = 0. $$

Is this part of the proof clear enough for you?

> Conversely, suppose that 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u = 0. $$
>   Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then there exists an $N$ such that (5) above holds for any $n > N$. That is, 
>   $$ \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u  < \varepsilon \tag{6} $$
>   for any $n > N$.
>
> Now let $s \in E$ be arbitrary. Then for any natural number $n$, using (2) above, we can conclude that
>   $$ d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) \leq \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert_u. $$
>   Finally from the last inequality and  (6) above we can conclude that
>   $$ d \left( f_n(s), f(s) \right) < \varepsilon $$
>   for all $s \in E$ and for any $n > N$.
>
> Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, it follows that our sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ converges uniformly to the function $f$ on set  $E$.

Hope you can get this now.

Comment: This answer is awesome!

Comment: @MathAvengers thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$.  But this only promises $\sup_x |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$.

Just talking about points for a second, every point in $(0,1)$ is ${}<1$, but the supremum of that set is $1$.